I'm developing a Chrome extension that aims to block URLs based on a blacklist fetched from an API
Problem Description

Issue: URLs are not being blocked as expected.
Expected behavior: When a URL matches one in the blacklist, it should be blocked dynamically.

Current implementation

I'm using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest to intercept requests.
I fetch the blacklist using fetchBlackList() which retrieves URLs correctly.
I compare the request URL with entries in the blacklist and attempt to block using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules.

Observations

I've verified that fetchBlackList() returns the expected URLs.
The comparison logic in isBlocked seems correct based on console logs.
However, URLs continue to load despite being in the blacklist.

What I've tried:
Implemented fetchBlackList():
Successfully retrieved the blacklist of URLs from my API using fetchBlackList(). Confirmed that the URLs returned are correct and match those in the database.
Comparison logic (isBlocked):
Implemented a comparison logic to check if the current request URL matches any URL in the fetched blacklist. Used RegExp to ensure accurate matching of domain and path.
Dynamic rule addition (chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules):
Attempted to add dynamic rules to block URLs that match entries in the blacklist. Generated unique rule IDs and set up blocking actions accordingly.
Debugging with console logs:
Used extensive logging (console.log) throughout the code to trace the flow of data and confirm that URLs are being evaluated correctly in the onBeforeRequest listener.
Expected outcome:
When a user tries to access a URL that is listed in the fetched blacklist, the Chrome extension should dynamically block that request before it's sent, using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules.

Please add the code (MCVE) to make the question answerable.
